# Problem with tikz plot in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, errors, plot

I'm trying to plot a function using this code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Draw the log-normal distribution curve
\draw[blue,smooth,thick] plot[id=f1,domain=0.001:6,samples=50]
function {(1/(0.5*x*(2*pi)**0.5))*exp(-ln(x)*ln(x)/0.5)};
% Draw the x-axis
\draw[->,black] (0,0) -- (6.5,0);
% Draw the y-axis
\draw[->,black] (0,0) -- (0,5);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The axis lines work fine but when I compile, I get strange errors and no pdf could be created. I followed the manual and many examples online and nothing works.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You need to use $\x$ in lieu of $x$.

Answer (score 4):

Via pgfplots, this is one solution.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=0.001:6,
    samples=50,
    grid=major,smooth,
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y(x)$, 
    legend pos=north east]
\addplot [color=red,thick]    {(1/(0.5*x*(2*pi)^0.5))*exp(-ln(x)*ln(x)/0.5)};
\legend{${\frac{1}{(0.5x(2\pi)^{0.5})}e^{-\frac{\ln(x)\ln(x)}{0.5}}}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Update:  This is another attempt using OP's desired method.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[blue,smooth,thick] 
 plot [id=exp,domain=0.001:6,samples=50]
(\x,{1/(0.5*\x*(2*pi)^(0.5))*exp(-ln(\x)*ln(\x)/0.5)}); 
% Draw the x-axis 
\draw[->,black] (0,0) -- (6.5,0); 
% Draw the y-axis 
\draw[->,black] (0,0) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Update 2: If `gnuplot` is desired. This is how. natural log function `ln` is wrong for `gnuplot`, should have been `log`. This method requires `gnuplot` installed and external call using

```
pdflatex -enable-write18 (or -shell-escape) filename.tex
```

[image]

Code for `gnuplot` scheme.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
%Draw the log-normal distribution curve
\draw[blue,smooth,thick]
 plot [id=test,domain=0.001:6,samples=50] function 
{(1/(0.5*x*(2*pi)**0.5))*exp(-log(x)*log(x)/0.5)};
%\draw[blue,smooth,thick]            % keep this command here for comparison purpse
%plot [domain=0.001:6,samples=50]
%(\x,{1/(0.5*\x*(2*pi)^(0.5))*exp(-ln(\x)*ln(\x)/0.5)});
% Draw the x-axis
\draw[->,black] (0,0) -- (6.5,0);
% Draw the y-axis
\draw[->,black] (0,0) -- (0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse. You suggestion works but I'm still puzzled why the first code didn't work. I'm also looking to remove the grid and markers on the axis and make them start both from 0.

Comment: @Chedly -- see my update please.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Except for the first trick you posted, none has worked. When I compile using PDFLatex I get the following error:

Runaway argument?
0.001:6\relax \else \pgfkeys@case@two \fi \fi \fi \pgfkeys@parse \pgfkeys@mains
top \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \tikz@plot@samples@recalc was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.205 \end{frame}
                 
? 

Process has been terminated ...

Comment: @Chedly -- I just cut and paste the code and run on my PC, yes they work as expected. Did you try XeLaTeX? For the 3rd case, you need gnuplot installed first.

Comment: Yes I tried XeLaTeX same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use `pgfplots` for plotting. However, the following works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
% Draw the log-normal distribution curve
\draw[blue,smooth,thick] plot[id=f1,domain=0.001:6,samples=50]
({\x,{(1/(0.5*\x*(2*pi)^0.5))*exp(-ln(\x)*ln(\x)/0.5)}});
% Draw the x-axis
\draw[->,black] (0,0) -- (6.5,0);
% Draw the y-axis
\draw[->,black] (0,0) -- (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Error was in your function definition.